# Run Maven in Docker container via current user

Tags: maven, docker

I want to run Maven to build a project in a Docker container. First, I came up with:

```
docker run -it --rm
           -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2:rw
           -v $PWD:$PWD:rw
           -w $PWD
           maven:alpine
           mvn "$@"
```

This builds fine, but the problem here is that all files are now written and owned by the `root` user. I want them to be owned by the current user, myself.

So I tried this:

```
docker run -it --rm
           --user $(id -u):$(id -g)
           -v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2:rw
           -v $PWD:$PWD:rw
           -w $PWD
           maven:alpine
           mvn "$@"
```

This did not work as expected. I believe I know why: now with `--user $(id -u):$(id -g)`, we are indeed executing as myself, but now the mapping of `-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2:rw` becomes incorrect, there is no `/root` in place anymore.

So let's try this:

```
docker run -it --rm
           --user $(id -u):$(id -g)
           -v $HOME:$HOME:rw
           -v $PWD:$PWD:rw
           -w $PWD
           maven:alpine
           mvn "$@"
```

Now I am getting the following warning:

```
Can not write to /root/.m2/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions? Carrying on ...
```

Also, Maven seems to be able to build (although I am having problems with accessing the Docker daemon during integration tests, but that might be better suited for another question), but I don't see any artifacts appearing in `~/.m2/repository` on the host? They are also not in `/root/.m2/repository` (which does not exist, as expected) on the host. Where are they? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven/) is described how to run maven as non-root-user:

> Maven needs the user home to download artifacts to, and if the user does not exist in the image an extra user.home Java property needs to be set.

Something in that direction should work:

```
docker run -it --rm \
  --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -v ~/.m2:/var/maven/.m2:rw \
  -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 \
  -v $PWD:$PWD:rw \
  -w $PWD \
  maven:alpine \
  mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven "$@"
```